# How to ensure JSON constant initialized first in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, constants, es6-promise

I'm new to Javascript and I don't know why this is wrong.

In the following code below, on **some** runs, it will claim that playerWinRates is undefined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lost' of undefined
    at file:///Users/bergholm/projects/FACEITDiscordBot/faceIt.js:296:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getPastMatchesByPlayer (file:///Users/bergholm/projects/FACEITDiscordBot/faceIt.js:284:16)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
undefined
(node:35193) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(node:35193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at bestWinRate (file:///Users/bergholm/projects/FACEITDiscordBot/faceIt.js:341:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (file:///Users/bergholm/projects/FACEITDiscordBot/bot.js:126:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:35193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

The code snippet I'm talking about is here, and it fails on `playerWinRates[map][mapWL[map]] += 1`

```
async function getPastMatchesByPlayer(playerId, numMatches = 20) {
    
    const response = await axios.get(
        "https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players/" +
            playerId +
            "/history?game=csgo&offset=0&limit=" +
            numMatches
    )
    const playerWinRates = {
        de_cache: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_dust2: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_mirage: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_nuke: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_overpass: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_train: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_inferno: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
        de_vertigo: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    }

    let matchIds = []
    let statsPromises = []
    response.data.items.forEach((match) => {
        matchIds.push(match.match_id)
        statsPromises.push(parseMatchWon(match, playerId))
    })
    const listOfResults = await Promise.all(statsPromises)
    listOfResults.forEach((mapWL) => {
    if (!mapWL) { // If null -- failed to get match, so ignore it
      console.log("Went into null/undefined")
      return
    }
    let map = Object.keys(mapWL)[0]
    playerWinRates[map][mapWL[map]] += 1
    })
    // The match id's are provided so that in the future they could be parsed to allow for more weight on different matches
    return { playerWinRates: playerWinRates, matchIds: matchIds }
}
```

EDIT: Removed function description because it took a lot of space and didnt help in this task

Comment: Add `console.log(mapWL, map)` just before `playerWinRates[map][mapWL[map]] += 1` to see for what value it fails. The last log just before the error will show you the last value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you cant `return` out of an `Array.forEach()` so where there is no value your not breaking out of the loop. I just switched your `forEach` to a `for in` loop.

Its hard to test locally, but let me know if this works.

```js
async function getPastMatchesByPlayer(playerId, numMatches = 20) {
/*  Retrieves the last 20 matches of the player
  FACEIT Data API GET /players/{player_id}/history
   Input:
   player_id * string (path) - The id of the player
   game * string (query) - A game on FACEIT
   from integer (query) - The timestamp (Unix time) as lower bound of the query. 1 month ago if not specified
   to integer (query) - The timestamp (Unix time) as higher bound of the query. Current timestamp if not specified
   offset integer (query) - The starting item position
   limit integer (query) - The number of items to return

   Request URL - https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players/20dcc7de-c82b-4d12-9bbd-b9c448b63888/history?game=csgo&offset=0&limit=20
*/
const response = await axios.get(
    "https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/players/" +
        playerId +
        "/history?game=csgo&offset=0&limit=" +
        numMatches
)
const playerWinRates = {
    de_cache: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_dust2: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_mirage: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_nuke: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_overpass: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_train: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_inferno: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
    de_vertigo: { won: 0, lost: 0 },
}

let matchIds = []
let statsPromises = []
response.data.items.forEach((match) => {
    matchIds.push(match.match_id)
    statsPromises.push(parseMatchWon(match, playerId))
})
const listOfResults = await Promise.all(statsPromises)
for(const listItem in listOfResults){
  const mapWL = listOfResults[listItem]
  if (!Object.keys(mapWL).length) { // If null -- failed to get match, so ignore it
    console.log("Went into null/undefined")
    return;
  }
  let map = Object.keys(mapWL)[0]
  if(map === 'won' || map === 'lost'){
    playerWinRates[map][mapWL[map]] += 1
  }

}

// The match id's are provided so that in the future they could be parsed to allow for more weight on different matches
return { playerWinRates: playerWinRates, matchIds: matchIds }
}
```

Comment: Hmm this didn't work for me. I tried yours as well as changing if (!mapWL) {...} to the opposite of if (mapWL) { ... } , but this shouldn't be the issue either.

It's not that the issue is from mapWL being undefined or null, but from playerWinRates being undefined

Comment: Can you change the conditional to be if(!Object.keys(mapWL).length) { return} the issue comes in how your uodating the object so maybe just make sure that there are keys in the mapWl object first. Is it guaranteed that mapWL's keys will map to player Win Rates?

Comment: I updated the code to be extra safe. So we are making sure there are even keys in that mapWL object and are making sure that it is in fact equaled to win or loss. I don't know anything about your data, but I think this covers your bases. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

So I made a huge error in judgement as I didn't realize that faceit has more than just the map pool as possible maps that can be played.

The constant would fail because of a map called "de_aimmap" that doesn't exist as a key. I fixed this with by changing the error throwing line to

`if (playerWinRates[map]) playerWinRates[map][key] += 1`

Thank you Grant Herman for putting so much effort!